# PHP extension "curl" must be loaded while installing on xampp Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, magento, curl, xampp

I am installing Magento on xampp local server on Windows 7. How to fix this error "PHP extension "curl" must be loaded." ?

Comment: I've got it: in php.ini the *;extension=php_curl.dll* should be changed to *extension=php_curl.dll*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uncomment the following line: `extension=php_curl.dll` in the php.ini configuration file of your XAMP.

The location of the php.ini file will be mostly

```
%XAMPP_HOME%/php/php.ini
```

Comment: I did. But not fixed. php version is 7.0.6, wamp version is 2.4

Answer (score 1):

**Stop apache and restart it.**

In the **xampp control panel** go to the **SCM tab** and then select **apache server** and stop it and again restart it.

Then, go to the installation page of magento and refresh the page.

The setting to change:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

to (semicolon removed)

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out something regarding this problem. First of all
doing the same under Wamp instead of Xampp (i.e. uncommenting the
extension=php_curl.dll line under the php and apache directories
causes an error because Wamp does not package this dll with its
distribution (at least as of wamp server 2.2). I had do ditch
wamp and install xampp to get magento running. Perhaps someone
can suggest where one can alternatively download the php_curl.dll
from so that magento can be brought to work with Wamp as well.

There is a magento checklist file at:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

This script has two problems. First the opening tag should be `<?php` rather than `<?`
or the xampp server wil not run it. Secondly the shell_exec() statement returnss an
empty array because the path to mysql is not configured, that's all, otherwise even
that part should be fine I suppose. (???)